# Creating an image and appending it to a div. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, dom

So what I want to do is gather images on the page and add them to a lightbox that pops up. So here is what I'm doing...

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
      var div = document.getElementById('thediv');
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = images[i].src;
      div.appendChild(img);
}
```

but

```
div.appendChild(img);
```

is not working and it breaks everything. I can comment it out and everything else I have (for instance, pop up the lightbox) works fine, so I know there is something wrong with that line but I'm not sure what is wrong with it. So my question is what am I doing wrong with that line?

Comment: What do you get in the console if you add `console.log(img)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks everything?"

Comment: I suggest moving `var div = document.getElementById('thediv');` outside the loop.  You don't need to search the DOM for it each loop, just once.

Comment: -1 for `is not working and it breaks everything`. Come on.

Comment: @JaredPar I mean nothing afterwards will run. But I'll take a look at Matt's suggestion as obviously an infinite loop would mean nothing else would run.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I thought what I wrote immediately after I said that explained what I was seeing. Sorry I didn't say it specifically how you would have liked.

Comment: @townie: What you didn't do is present a testcase and describe your program's behaviour. You don't do that anywhere in your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094) returns a [**live** `NodeList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), [which will *automatically* add](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#td-live) any new elements which match the selector (in this case any `img` element) to it's collection.

Because of this, you're getting into an infinite loop (as the size of `images` is growing by 1 with each iteration). The *easiest* way to fix this (with one *massive caveat*) is to simply cache the size of the `images` collection *before* you start adding more;

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var len = images.length;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
      var div = document.getElementById('thediv');
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = images[i].src;
      div.appendChild(img);
}
// to see what happens, try alerting images.length now to see the length has changed.
```

**However**, this assumes that the newly added elements will get added to the *end* of the `NodeList`; however this is *only* the case when the element added is the last in the DOM
 (which will usually *not* be the case/ cannot be guaranteed).

Because of this, you end up with having to copy the `NodeList` returned into an array, and *then* iterating over that;

```
// Create an array
var images = [];

// Copy the result of getElementsByTagName in to the array
for (var i=0, ar = document.getElementsByTagName('img');i<ar.length;i++) {
    images.push(ar[i]);
}

for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
      var div = document.getElementById('thediv');
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = images[i].src;
      div.appendChild(img);
}
```

A less-dry (compared to the W3 spec!) article that explains this in more detail  can be found on the [MDC website](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList#A_.22live.22_collection).

Comment: Certainly didn't know about it being live. Thanks! It works perfectly and good to know my logic wasn't wrong, just my understanding of getElementsByTagName().

Comment: This is still - potentially - problematic, since, as you say, the NodeList returned is live. If it's working in a given situation, it must be because the images are being added at a spot later in the DOM than all those found by the original call to getElementsByTagName(). I.e. there must be NO img elements after div#thediv.